# ACTION_GET_CONTENT gives wrong path

Tags: java, android

I'm using ACTION_GET_CONTENT so that the user can select text files that the rest of my code can read and deal with.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select data"), SELECT_DATA);
```

Above is my code so that the user can browse which works fine.

```
Uri DataUri = data.getData();
File FileUri = new File(DataUri.getPath());
```

If I convert DataUri or FileUri to a string after using getPath or getAbsolutePath, I get a completely wrong path.

The path should be /storage/emulated/0/Documents/myFile but it gives me /document/primary:Documents/myFile. I have no idea what this "primary:Documents" thing is.

The data from the intent itself already has the wrong path, any suggestions?

Comment: `The path should be ...` what makes you think that? What makes you think that Uri you receive represents a file object? there are many other types of resources that can be represented by a Uri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using ACTION_GET_CONTENT so that the user can select text files

No, you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` so that the user can select some content that has a MIME type of `text/*`. Where that content comes from is largely up to the user. It may or may not be a file on the filesystem, and if it is, is may or may not be a file that you could access yourself directly (e.g., internal storage of the Dropbox app, files on removable storage on Android 4.4+ devices).

> The path should be /storage/emulated/0/Documents/myFile

No, it should not.

> but it gives me /document/primary:Documents/myFile

What you get will vary by whatever activity handles the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request. What that activity is will depend on what the user has installed that supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and what the user chooses out of that list of installed stuff.

Usually, you will get a `content` `Uri` (i.e., `getScheme()` on `Uri` will return `content`), as the `Uri` will point to data being served by a `ContentProvider`.

> The data from the intent itself already has the wrong path

It has the correct path. It is simply not a path on the filesystem.

> any suggestions?

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` for the content represented by the `content` `Uri`.

Comment: I see now. I didn't fully understand ACTION_GET_CONTENT so its a bit clearer now for sure. Would using `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(DataUri)));` be identical? It doesn't seem to work still. I am passing it as a string into a string array, converting it back using Uri.parse(UriString) and then opening a stream with that Uri however.

Comment: @Marakalastic: "Would using... be identical?" -- identical to what? "I am passing it as a string into a string array, converting it back using Uri.parse(UriString) and then opening a stream with that Uri however" -- make sure the `Uri` you get after all that is the same `Uri` that you started with. Also, bear in mind that these `Uri` values are short-lived. You can't persist them, for example, planning on using them again the next time that your app runs. Think of them as akin to a Web server URL that requires a session cookie.

Comment: I meant identical to using just ContentResolver but I realize that's the same thing. And yes, it is the same, just done in different methods but in the same activity. I know the Uri is the same because I printed our the Uri from my array afterwards before the exception occurs. Also, I pretty much copy and pasted the entire `getContentResolver` code as well. The only difference was I didn't change it from an Uri to a string and back. Originally, I wanted to store a bunch of paths in an array so that I could open them all one by one. I've opted now to store the data as a string in the array.

Comment: @Marakalastic: "It doesn't seem to work still" -- what specifically are your symptoms?

Comment: Sorry, by "it doesn't seem to work still", I mean I get the FileNotFoundException. Instead of `BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(DataUri)));` being in the same method as where I receive the intent data, I had it in a different method with `Uri.parse(DataUriString)` and was getting the exception here. Performing BufferedReader in the same method solved this issue.

Comment: @Marakalastic: If you could, edit your question and post the full stack trace (since stack traces don't work well in SO comments...). "Performing BufferedReader in the same method solved this issue" -- that strongly suggests that the `Uri` after your array work was different than the `Uri` from before the array work.

Comment: No need I think! I did something really stupid. I was putting `DataUri.getPath()` into the array instead of `DataUri.toString()` so when I parsed it back to Uri, it wouldn't like that!

Comment: @Marakalastic: Yup, that'll do it.